# Every minute a GET request is sent to my Server even though the request is a POST request, and I never call the function

Tags: swift, post, server, get, http-status-code-405

I am building an app using swift that is based around the idea of streaks. You open the app, log in, and the server sends back your information based on your login. I have a function, called
`resetStreak` that sends a POST request to the server giving it the username (thats how i manage each users information- based on their username) and telling the server to update their information, setting their streak to 0. Here is the code:

```swift
func resetStreak(){
        print("Started resetSTREAK!!")
        let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/resetstreak/")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let jsonData = "\"\(username)\""
        print(jsonData)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //request.httpBody = thetask.data(using: .utf8)
        request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let thenewtask = jsonData.data(using: .utf8) //string into data format
        request.httpBody = thenewtask
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        let decodedTasks = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
                        self.LoginResponse = decodedTasks
                        print("Decoded Tasks: \(decodedTasks)")
                        print("Login Response: \(LoginResponse)")
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I have almost identical code like this, sending other POST request with different information which is why I know it shouldn't be erroring. however, I NEVER CALL THIS FUNCTION. and yet, I keep getting this error on my server:
[image: image of error]

As for the code on the server, it shouldn't matter as it receieves a GET request every minute. This is the code it has:

```py
@app.route("/resetstreak/", methods = ['POST'])
def reset_streak():
    print("RESETTING STREAK")
    username = request.json # username
```

I do, however, have something added that is probably the cause of the issue. Since I would like to reset the user's streak after two days, I need to check if it has been 2 days since their last completed task! I implemented a timer that updates every minute, and does something. This is the code:

```swift
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

  var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("\(getStreak())")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                
                
                    .onReceive(timer) { time in //updates every minute
                        print("TIMER ACTIVATED")
                        let dayDistance = compareCompletedTasks()
                        let theStreak = getStreak()
                        if dayDistance == 2 && theStreak != "loading..." && Int(theStreak)! > 0{ //they missed a day (reset streak)
                            //resetStreak()
                            print("reset streak")
                        }
                    }
```

please note that I changed the timer to 1 second, still the error occurs every minute. it never prints "reset streak" either which is super odd. PLEASE HELP! I will put the whole file of code if needed, because I am not good at asking questions.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation




extension Date {
    func get(_ components: Calendar.Component..., calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> DateComponents {
        return calendar.dateComponents(Set(components), from: self)
    }

    func get(_ component: Calendar.Component, calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> Int {
        return calendar.component(component, from: self)
    }
}






struct HomeScreen: View {
    
    @Binding var username: String
    @Binding var LoginResponse: [String]    
    @Binding var lastCompleted: String
    
    @State var lastCompletedList: [String] = []
    @State var currentDate = Date()
    @State var tasks: [String] = []
    
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    let date = Date()
    let df = DateFormatter()
    

    
    func daysBetweenDates(year1: Int, month1: Int, day1: Int, year2: Int, month2: Int, day2: Int) -> Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let startDateComponents = DateComponents(year: year1, month: month1, day: day1)
        let endDateComponents = DateComponents(year: year2, month: month2, day: day2)
        
        guard let startDate = calendar.date(from: startDateComponents),
              let endDate = calendar.date(from: endDateComponents) else {
            return 0
        }
        
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
        return abs(components.day ?? 0)
    }
    
    func getTaskNumber() -> Int { //number will always go up
        let currentDate = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let currentDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: currentDate)
        
        return daysBetweenDates(
            year1: 2023,
            month1: 8,
            day1: 3,
            year2: currentDateComponents.year ?? 0,
            month2: currentDateComponents.month ?? 0,
            day2: currentDateComponents.day ?? 0
        )
    }
    
    func getCurDate() -> String {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let currentDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: currentDate)
        
        if let year = currentDateComponents.year, let month = currentDateComponents.month, let day = currentDateComponents.day {
            return "\(year) \(month) \(day)"
        } else {
            return "Date components not available"
        }
    } //returns a string of the date with each number seperated by a space


    func compareCompletedTasks() -> UInt{ //returns
        let lastCompletedDate = lastCompleted.components(separatedBy: " ") //split it into a list
        let curDate = getCurDate().components(separatedBy: " ")
        
        let dayDiff = daysBetweenDates(year1: Int(lastCompletedDate[0])!, month1: Int(lastCompletedDate[1])!, day1: Int(lastCompletedDate[2])!, year2: Int(curDate[0])!, month2: Int(curDate[1])!, day2: Int(curDate[2])!) //equal to the number of days from the last time they did a task, and today
        //if its still the same day
        if dayDiff == 0{
            return 0
        }
        //if its been 1 day
        if dayDiff == 1{
            return 1
        }
        //if its been 2 or more days
        return 2
        
    }




    
    
    func completeTask(){
        let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/addtostreak/")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        //let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:thetask)
        
        let jsonData = "\"\(username),\(getCurDate())\""
        print(jsonData)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //request.httpBody = thetask.data(using: .utf8)
        request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let thenewtask = jsonData.data(using: .utf8) //string into data format
        request.httpBody = thenewtask
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        let decodedTasks = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
                        self.LoginResponse = decodedTasks
                        print("Decoded Tasks: \(decodedTasks)")
                        print("Login Response: \(LoginResponse)")
                        lastCompletedList = LoginResponse[2].components(separatedBy: " ")
                        lastCompleted = "\(lastCompletedList[0]) \(lastCompletedList[1]) \(lastCompletedList[2])"
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func getTasks() { // make the http request
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/tasks/") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }
        
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        let decodedTasks = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
                        self.tasks = decodedTasks
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        dataTask.resume()
    }
    
    
    func resetStreak(){
        print("Started resetSTREAK!!")
        let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/resetstreak/")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let jsonData = "\"\(username)\""
        print(jsonData)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //request.httpBody = thetask.data(using: .utf8)
        request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let thenewtask = jsonData.data(using: .utf8) //string into data format
        request.httpBody = thenewtask
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        let decodedTasks = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
                        self.LoginResponse = decodedTasks
                        print("Decoded Tasks: \(decodedTasks)")
                        print("Login Response: \(LoginResponse)")
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    
    func getTask(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> String{
        if tasks.count == 0{
            return "loading..."
        }
        return tasks[getTaskNumber() % tasks.count]
    }
    
    func getStreak() -> String{
        if LoginResponse.count < 2{
            return "loading..."
        }
        return LoginResponse[1]
    }
    
    
    func flameColor() -> Color{
        if isComplete(){ // if they did their task for today
            return Color.red
        }
        return Color.gray //they didnt do their task today
    }
    
    func buttonColor() -> Color{
        if isComplete(){ // if they did their task for today
            return Color.gray
        }
        return Color.red //they didnt do their task today
    }


    
    func getTime() -> String{
        df.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
        df.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
        return df.string(from: currentDate)
    }
    
    
    func getTheTime(from date: Date) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ss"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    func isComplete() -> Bool{
        let lastCompletedDate = lastCompleted.components(separatedBy: " ") //split it into a list
        let curDate = getCurDate().components(separatedBy: " ")
        //return true if they did the task today
        //return false if they didnt do the task today
        if lastCompletedDate[0] == curDate[0] && lastCompletedDate[1] == curDate[1] && lastCompletedDate[2] == curDate[2]{
            return true
        }
        return false
        
    }
    
    func todaysTask() -> String{
        if isComplete(){ //if they did their task today
            return "Completed"
        }
        return getTask(year: currentDate.get(.year), month: currentDate.get(.month), day: currentDate.get(.day))
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("\(getStreak())")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                
                
                    .onReceive(timer) { time in //updates every minute
                        print("TIMER ACTIVATED")
                        let dayDistance = compareCompletedTasks()
                        let theStreak = getStreak()
                        if dayDistance == 2 && theStreak != "loading..." && Int(theStreak)! > 0{ //they missed a day (reset streak)
                            //resetStreak()
                            print("reset streak")
                        }
                    }
                
                
                Text(Image(systemName: "flame.fill"))
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(flameColor())
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack{
                Text("Task")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(todaysTask())
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding()
                    
                    //.overlay {Rectangle().stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 5)}
                Button(action: completeTask){
                    Text("Complete")
                        .padding()
                        .overlay{
                            Rectangle().stroke(.black, lineWidth: 3)
                        }
                        .background(buttonColor())
                    
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                .disabled(isComplete())
//                Text(getTheTime(from: currentDate))
//                    .onReceive(timer) { input in
//                        currentDate = input
//                        print(currentDate)
//                    }
            }
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
                .frame(width: 10000, height: 150)
        }
        .background(.green)
        .onAppear(perform: getTasks)
        
        
    }
}

struct HomeScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var placeHolder: [String] = ["123456", "0", "2022 1 1"]
    @State static var placeHolder2: String = ""
    @State static var placeHolder3: String = "2022 1 1"

    static var previews: some View {
        HomeScreen(username: $placeHolder2, LoginResponse: $placeHolder, lastCompleted: $placeHolder3)
    }
}
```

I stopped calling the function expecting the error to stop, it never did.
I reset my computer hoping it would fix, it didn't
I changed the timer requency hoping the error would then happen every second, it didn't. It happened every minute still

Comment: put a break point in the code that you think is generating the request.  Is the breakpoint actually hit?  If not, the cause is elsewhere (which the GET/POST discrepancy suggests).  If it is, work your way up the stack trace to see the execution flow and how the method you think can't be called actually is being.